# Library file for c# dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a relatively new c#.net programmer and need some advice on adding a Library file to a c# project.

This project is not done in proper C# fashion and I realize that, but am not looking to solve that today.

I have 3 .aspx pages and each has a corresponding .cs file set up as a code behind.  That all works fine.

Each of the .cs files has several functions that identical.  I'd like to move those common functions into a common .cs file that is used by all of the .aspx pages (or the .cs files if that is how to do it) while keeping the unique code behind files for functions unique to that aspx/cs pair.

Once the common file is created (it already is), How do I reference that file this as simply as possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your project should have an App_Code folder.   Visual Studio will automatically look in this location for classes.   If you place your common class in that folder, you can directly access that class in your .aspx.cs codebehind files.

No need to add any references.

Comment: I did that how do I reference it? i.e. using XXXXXX

Comment: Visual studio automatically detect those classes in your code behind files.

Comment: I'm not able to call the class, there has to be something else I need to do. Where "DoStuff3" is the function, and I call it on page load in the .cs as DoStuff3();  I get "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'DoStuff3' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: for example you have a `Sample` as a class and `DIsplay` as method in that class,then you have to acess that method in your page as `New Sample().Dispaly()`. if you are method is `Static` then you can acess it by `Sample.Dispaly()` and method should not be Private.

Comment: My class/method file contains:    static class pti_Library2
    {
        public void DoStuff3()
        {
            Response.Write("I'm doing 333 something...");
        }
    }
    
    and I call it like pti_Library2().DoStuff3();
    
    and get this error
    
    CS0103: The name 'pti_Library2' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I've changed that m but still get  "CS0103: The name 'pti_Library2' does not exist in the current context
"

Comment: sorry i forgot to tell you ,app_code classes should not declared as static,change your class to public class pti_Library2{}.

Comment: Can you post the entire class code in the question please which is in app_code?

Comment: public class pti_Library2
    {
        public static void DoStuff3()
        {
            Response.Write("I'm doing 333 something...");
        }
    }

Comment: how you are calling this method?.

Comment: contained in here          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //WriteRFC();
            getHost();
            chkLogin();
            getMenu();
            pti_Library2.DoStuff3();


        }

Comment: you are getting the same error.are you geting this classname in intelisense?

Comment: Intellisnse does not autocomplete, but does not give me an error in red with "pti_Library2.DoStuff3();" - but I do get red lines under DoStuff3() for "New pti_Library2.DoStuff3();"

Comment: it should not be `New pti_Library2.DoStuff3()`,it should be `pti_Library2.DoStuff3()` as DoStuff3() is static method.

Comment: I don't use the "New " prefix, that was just an example that throws an intellisense warning.  I'm using "pti_Library2.DoStuff3();" and get the complier error "CS0103: The name 'pti_Library2' does not exist in the current context" but NO intellisense warning or error

Comment: where did you put your class,i mean which folder?

Comment: the class file, ptiLibrary.cs is in the App_Code folder.

Comment: pti_Library2 is the public class contained in ptiLibrary.cs.  DoStuff3() is a function in pti_Library2

Comment: ptiLibrary.cs consists of public class pti_Library2
    {
        public static void DoStuff3()
        {
            Response.Write("I'm doing 333 something...");
        }
    }

Comment: have you added new folder and named it as App_Code or you have added defined App_Code folder?

Comment: I added the App_Code folder through windows explorer

Comment: ok,delete that folder you have created from windows explorer and go to your solution explorer and right click on your website and Add Asp.Net Folder menu and add App_Code folder to your solution and place your class in that folder.Now try it.

Comment: Solution explorer is empty, I created each file individually in VS2010

Comment: what do you mean solution explorer empty?

Comment: where you created this folder and where you are accesing this class method?

Comment: View--> Solution Explorer does not show any contents in the Solution Explorer Pane

Comment: where are your files then?

Comment: how you are running this ?

Comment: I created a folder in windows explorer called pti which is off of my wwwroot where I run all my websites.  I created all files in VS2010, but did not create a project whcih I have never had to do. That all runs fine.

Comment: restart your IIs and run the application again.

Comment: I've used Classic ASP for 15 years and write in .net the same way, this may explain my amateur way of doing things, thank you again for all of your help so far

Comment: I restarted IIS, vut still get this message "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'pti_Library2' does not exist in the current context
"

Comment: Can you do one thing ,create a new web application and add these files to that application and try to build that application?

Comment: I'll do that as I've done some reading during our conversation and I seems to be the proper thing.

Comment: I need to leave to visit a customer and will be offline for the rest of today.  I'll update tomorrow as to what happened - thank you again very much.